# Is there a function I can use to manually select a value in a listbox in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have two Userforms, one that has many listboxes and exports that data to another spreadsheet. I have a second Userform that is identical to the first one, however when you open it, it should have the values of each list and text box automatically selected from the spreadsheet. Then, when you complete it, it should essentially replace where the old line item was. (Example: if I'm editing a plan originally on row 35, then it will replace the data from there and fill it in) My problem is when I click submit, if I hadn't touched some of these listboxes (because there was no need to edit them), the values on the spreadsheet disappear.

I ran some tests to see if it was hiding the value or what, and have determined that the value of the listboxes or "", for some reason, unless I click a different value, or even the same value. I just have to click a value inside of the listbox for it to populate on the spreadsheet. I've tried to incorporate the Listbox.Select function but to no avail, as I didn't know how to essentially "save" the data from the previous row.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim activeRow As Long
activeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(PlanName_text.Value, Range("B:B"), 0)

'Clear FinalForm_list
FinalForm_list.Clear

'Fill FinalForm_list
With FinalForm_list
    .AddItem "2018"
    .AddItem "2019"
    .AddItem "2020"
    .AddItem "2021"
    .AddItem "2022"
    .AddItem "2023"
End With

'Sets Final Form Year equal to what the spreadsheet says
FinalForm_list.Value = Cells(activeRow, 11).Value

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub complete_active_Click() 'complete_active = "done" button

Dim activeRow As Long
activeRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(PlanName_text.Value, Range("B:B"), 0)


Cells(activeRow, 11).Value = FinalForm_list.Value

Unload Me
End Sub
```

I really just want to be able to go into this edit form, with all of values from the spreadsheet already selected, change one or two values and leave the rest alone, and still have the values on the spreadsheet be the same as what they were and not disappear.

Comment: You've got your code to manually select a value in a listbox already written. just apply `Listbox.Value = valueInListbox` to all the listboxes you need the values to default to in the initialization just like you did with `FinalForm_list.Value = Cells(activeRow, 11).Value`

Comment: Are you saying I should add something to this code, or add something to the rest of my code? Because this one doesn't work, if I have a value predefined and go into the form, edit something else but now FinalForm, it just disappears

Comment: Austin, when you answer someone in comments you need to "ping" them by putting a @ before the name. Otherwise, there's no notification. So @TateGarringer, for example :-)